# Issue with bootstrap horizontal form and table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I have put a table into a bootstrap form with the class "form-horizontal", I get some strange behaviour where the table contents end up moving 1 cell to the right when compared to the header.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form action="some_action" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Name">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" value="" name="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="">
        <fieldset class="border">
          <legend>
            Events
          </legend>
          <table id="eventList" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr class="event-header">
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id="template" class="event-record form-group form-inline">
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control" id="One" name="One" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control" id="Two" name="Two" type="text" value="">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Clear All</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/488jrvzz/)

Hack is to add a extra 'th' cell in the header, but it is not perfect as the layout is not quite exact.

Removing form-horizontal also fixes the issue, but then that looses the styling for the other elements outside the table that require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have given the class `.form-group`, which changes the `display` to `block`. If you please remove the concerned class, it will be alright. Give it to a `<div>` encapsulating both.